# How to Display the Student Name in their Respective Courses

Tags: c

I'm having troubles displaying the names of the students
for their respective course... and that is the only problem I've
had...

Thank you very much

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define p printf
#define s scanf
struct stud
{
  char name[50];
  char course1[50];
  char course2[50];
  char course3[50];
  char course[50];
  int course_code;
}c[5];
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int input_code,i,bsit_list=0,bscpe_list=0,bscs_list=0;

  for (i=0; i<5; i++)
  {
    strcpy(c[i].course1,"BSIT");
    strcpy(c[i].course2,"BSCPE");
    strcpy(c[i].course3,"BSCS");

    p("\n[%d] Enter Student Name: ",i+1);
    s("%s",c[i].name);
    p("   [1] %s",c[i].course1);
    p("\n   [2] %s",c[i].course2);
    p("\n   [3] %s",c[i].course3);
    p("\nEnter Student Code: ");
    s("%d",&input_code);

    if (input_code==1)
     {
       bsit_list++;
       strcpy(c[i].course,"BSIT");
     }
    else if (input_code==2)
     {
       bscpe_list++;
       strcpy(c[i].course,"BSCPE");
     }
    else if (input_code==3)
     {
       bscs_list++;
       strcpy(c[i].course,"BSCS");
     }
   }

  p("\nBSIT Students");
  for (i=0; i<input_code==1; i++)
   {
     p("\nName: %s",c[i].name); `<----- This is where my problem starts`
   }
  p("\nCount: %d",bsit_list);

  p("\n\nBSCPE Students");
  for (i=0; i<input_code==2; i++)
   {
     p("\nName: %s",c[i].name);   `<----- Also this`
   }
  p("\nCount: %d",bscpe_list);

  p("\n\nBSCS Students");
  for (i=0; i<input_code==3; i++)
   {
     p("\nName: %s",c[i].name);   `<----- And this`
   }
  p("\nCount: %d",bscs_list);

  getch();
}
```

Comment: `#define p printf` and `#define s scanf` causes a LOT of problems! Remove those and type `printf` and `scanf` manually. Also, what is `i<input_code==1`,`i<input_code==2` and `i<input_code==3`?

Comment: What specifically is the problem? Do you see anything printed? Is it just formatting?

Comment: Well the input_code==1 is for the BSIT course to display.. and input_code==2 for BSCPE and input_code==3 for BSCS

Comment: `i<input_code==2` might mean something peculiar (the loop could iterate once) if `==` had precedence over `<` but it doesn't. This is equivalent to `(i<input_code)==2` which never evaluates to `1 (true)` so the loop is never iterated.

Comment: The `i<input_code==2` (and the other similar expressions) will be interpreted as `(i<input_code) == 2` which will **always be false**, since the relational check `i < input_code` will be either false (`0`) or true (`1`). What is intended with this expression is unclear. I understand checking if `input_code == 2` but why is the `i <` in front of it?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here

```
p("\nBSIT Students");
for (i=0; i<input_code==1; i++)
          |--------------|
   {
     p("\nName: %s",c[i].name); `<----- This is where my problem starts`
   }
```

what you want is

```
p("\nBSIT Students");
for (i=0; i<5; i++)                  //iterate over all the students
   {
     if(!strcmp(c[i].course, c[i].course1)) //check for the match
     printf("Name: %s\n",c[i].name);
   }
```

Similar for other courses also.

Note: I prefer `printf()` and `scanf()` over `p()` and `s()`. YMMV.

Comment: Thank you Very Much... You are the answer to my prayer :D

Comment: @AaronTumbokon , don't forget to mark the answer as the accepted answer ( click the tick mark next to the answer ) if this is the correct solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as everyone has suggested, `printf()` and `scanf()` are better.

I noticed that you have a variable `course_code` in your struct that you have not used, so I used it to store the `item_code` of each student.

Now, the `i<item_code==1` is wrong.
What you need is `i<5` ( since the number of students is 5 ) and then later, just use an `if( c[i].course_code == 1 )` statement before outputting the names.

Here is a fixed version of your code ( only the part where I have made changes )

```
    c[i].course_code = input_code;      // the cource_code is assigned
    if ( input_code == 1 )
     {
       bsit_list++;
       strcpy( c[i].course , "BSIT" );
     }
    else if ( input_code == 2 )
     {
       bscpe_list++;
       strcpy( c[i].course , "BSCPE" );
     }
    else if ( input_code == 3 )
     {
       bscs_list++;
       strcpy( c[i].course , "BSCS" );
     }
  }

  p("\nBSIT Students");

  for ( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
    {
       if( c[i].course_code == 1 )       // this if statement is what is required
         p("\nName: %s",c[i].name); 
    }
  p("\nCount: %d",bsit_list);


  p("\n\nBSCPE Students");

  for ( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
   {
     if( c[i].course_code == 2 )       // this if statement is what is required
        p("\nName: %s",c[i].name);   
   }
  p("\nCount: %d",bscpe_list);


  p("\n\nBSCS Students");

  for ( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
   {
     if( c[i].course_code == 3 )       // this if statement is what is required
        p("\nName: %s",c[i].name);   
   }
  p("\nCount: %d",bscs_list);
```